# inserting new data into access

Tags: c#, insert, oledb

I'd like to insert a new row of data into my oledb. I simply structured my codes the way I did with UPDATE. However, there's error with **OleDbCommand ins = new OleDbCommand(insertString, strOleDbConnectionString);**

How does it actually work without using tableadapters or parameters etc?

```
        string strOleDbConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Project.mdb";
        OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(strOleDbConnectionString);

        string insertString = "INSERT INTO jiahe ([Tag ID], User, Age, [Phone Number]) VALUES (123, Esther, 19, 92786618)";
        string newTagID = textBox1.Text;
        string newUser = textBox2.Text;
        string newAge = textBox3.Text;
        string newPhoneNumber = textBox4.Text;

        OleDbCommand ins = new OleDbCommand(insertString, strOleDbConnectionString);

        ins.Connection.Open();

        ins.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();

        ins.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: shouldn't Esther be single qouted 'Esther'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like a simple error in your query..

if User is a string (don't know about the rest) it should be simple quoted

```
"INSERT INTO jiahe ([Tag ID], User, Age, [Phone Number]) VALUES (123, 'Esther', 19, 92786618)"
```

Also, the oledbcommand receive a connection object, not a connection string. try with

```
OleDbCommand ins = new OleDbCommand(insertString, objConnection );
```